# Kafka retention policyoverride

Tags: apache-kafka

I have created my topic when the retention policy in server.properties was set to 168 hours (7 days)
then changed the retention policy to 10 days since the topic has created at the time does it inherit server.properties of 7 days has been set as a part of topic creation as topic properties,

I did not alter the topic to customize the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not specify an override when you created the topic, it uses the current value from `server.properties` and every time you update the value in `server.properties`, the new value will be taken into account when applying the retention policies.

A quick way to double check if you have any override is to run:

`./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ZK --describe --topic TOPICNAME`

Comment: I tried describing the topic, it does not return any topic specific properties.